# Trying to set user control height to 100% within grid

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm having problems trying to set a user control to 100% height of the second row of the grid. My UserControl has no attributes for width/height (Auto).  The code below puts the user control over the Label control... I haven't the slightest clue what I may doing wrong.  Any ideas?

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <sdk:Label Content="Task Configuration" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#1E000000" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5,0,0,0" >
    </sdk:Label>
    <my:TaskConfig  Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can try `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`, but really it depends on what `my:TaskConfig` contains.

Comment: It contains another grid with some labels and textboxes.

Comment: Try `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` instead and remove the height Auto declaration. Otherwise, another trick I use (very rarely, but occasionally) is put something simple in the same spot to render behind it, like a Transparent `Rectangle` that you know will fill the space, then bind the other element to its `ActualHeight` like `Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Otherthingy}"` but that limits resize capability. Overall like McGarnagle pointed out, would need to see all the pieces to understand how they fit together.

Comment: Removing Height="Auto" and added the stretch component seems to do the trick.  Thanks!